# How to set the grow rate of database in SQLserver

Tags: sql-server

How to set the grow rate of database in SQLserver? My database have huge size about 42 GB but the default auto grow size is 1 M. I think it is very inefficiency for the grow size of the Database.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on your database and choose Properties.  Then choose Files.  This will allow you to change the Initial size as well as Autogrowth and file size limits for your data and log files.

You should also enable [Instant File Initialization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2009/12/22/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization/) (if possible).

Check [this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/) for some excellent guidance on autogrowth.

Answer (score 1):

You should monitor your database files in order to know how much they grow per load period. Based on this, you can set the amount that gives you good performance. Basically, SQL Server shouldn't request space too frequently and should avoid asking for more space during heavy loads.

You can find here how to set up the parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175890.aspx

And here there are some advices about which should be the correct value: https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/blitz-result-percent-growth-use/